# How to use -interaction=nonstopmode option with make4ht?

Tags: make4ht

The htlatex way

```
$ make4ht document.tex "customcfg.cfg, charset=utf-8" " -cunihtf -utf8" "" "-interaction=nonstopmode"
```

didn't work. Result was:

> make4ht:unrecognized parameter: i.

I would also prefer make4ht's own argument system.

```
$ make4ht -u -c customcfg.cfg document.tex
```

Maybe this can be achieved by creating custom build file, but documentation (https://github.com/michal-h21/make4ht) for make4ht is somewhat difficult to understand because I don't know lua very well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit 2022:

`make4ht` now runs in the non-stop mode by default. It also hides most of the command line output, showing only errors and warnings detected by `make4ht`. I've added the `-a` (or `--loglevel`) command line option, which can modify this behavior. You can use various log levels (`error`, `warning`, `notice`, `debug`). The `debug` log level is the same as the original method, so it shows full terminal output, and also stops on errors, waiting for the user action.

```
$ make4ht -a debug filename.tex
```

---

*Original answer*:

In the distributed version of `make4ht`, you must add spaces before options passed to `tex4ht`, `t4ht` and `latex`, so the correct `make4ht` invocation should be:

```
 $ make4ht document.tex "customcfg.cfg, charset=utf-8" " -cunihtf -utf8" "" " -interaction=nonstopmode"
```

I've just figured out a fix for this issue, you can test it if you want to install the development version of `make4ht` from Github. It should be possible to normally call

```
 $ make4ht document.tex "customcfg.cfg, charset=utf-8" "-cunihtf -utf8" "" "-interaction=nonstopmode"
```

without those spaces.

As for the `.mk4` build file, you can modify the parameters to LaTeX using `settings` table. The following `.mk4` file suffices:

```
 settings.latex_par = settings.latex_par .. " -interaction=nonstopmode"
```

The `latex_par` variable contains parameters with LaTeX command line options.

Comment: Great! The development version from github seems to fix the problem. Thank you!

Comment: is it `--interaction=` or `-interaction=` ? it seems it works both cases? Btw, I just added `"-interaction=batchmode"` to my make4ht command and it works, but I still see `--interaction=errorstopmode` in there?. But the batchmode takes over, since it shows after it in the command. It should have replaced it? Here is screen shot ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ABVZ4.png)

Comment: fyi, it also _did not replace_ it, when I used `"--interaction=batchmode"` (with 2 dashes). But still show up. Not big deal because the one I want takes over as it shows after it. but may be this should not happen?

Comment: @Nasser `make4ht` uses `--interaction=nonstopmode` by default now. It shows LaTeX output only with the `-a debug' option.